# Find out which object another object belongs to in a ArrayList

Tags: java, object, arraylist

- I have a classes called Sys, Depot and VehicleMover.
- The Sys has a ArrayList of Depots.
- Each Depot has a ArrayList of VehicleMovers.
- Inside the VehicleMover class I want to have a method called
  addVehicle that adds a vehicle to the depot the vehicleMover belongs
  to.

Is there a way of knowing which depot a VehicleMover belongs to inside the code for VehicleMover without having to pass it through as a parameter of addVehicle?

Comment: At the very least, the VehicleMover would have to be able to get access to all of the Depots so it could search them. Does it have a reference to Sys? Also, can a VehicleMover belong to more than one Depot? What should happen if it does?

Comment: Can a VehicleMover belong to more than one Depot?

Comment: If you're asking whether it's possible in java to know what objects have references to your object the answer is no, there is no way.

Comment: Yes, you have `VehicleMover` maintain a reference back to the `Depot` it belongs to. That's similar to how a `Child` class sometimes maintains a reference back to its `Parent` class, or a `TreeNode` class maintains references to both its parent (`parent`) and its children (`left` and `right`).

Comment: It is generally a bad practice to let code of some class manage another class. OOP means that you should write your classes as self-managed and encapsulated as possible, meaning that `Depot` class is responsible for adding vehicles to itself. If you `have` to do this from a `VehicleMover` instance, there is no other way than letting the `VehicleMover` class hold a reference to its `Depot` parent, which would probably passed to the `VehicleMover` constructor